# How could I create a "Authorize {App} to use your account" interface

Tags: twitter, oauth, bots

I'm currently working during my internship on a Twitter bot project, I can manage to schedule and post tweets but asking users for their secret Keys and tokens is a bit intimidating.
How could I create an interface like this one : 
[image: Authorize UI]

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [3-legged OAuth and sign-in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) in your application. Depending on the language you are using, you'll probably find a third-party [Twitter client library](https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries) that can help you.